# How do I turn an ip address into an array?

Tags: c++

I have

```
std::array<unsigned char, 4> ipv4 = {};
```

and IP adress 90.100.160.101, how do I add it to

```
peer.ipv4[0] = 90;
peer.ipv4[1] = 100;
peer.ipv4[2] = 160;
peer.ipv4[3] = 101;
```

Comment: You just did. What's the question? And what do you mean "add"? Summing IP addresses doesn't seem useful.

Comment: IP 90.100.160.101 I specified as an example, it can be different and it should be brought to the form as in the example

Comment: You wrote four statements, each assigning one octet of the address to an array. At the end of this process, you have "turned an IP address into an array". The array `peer.ipv4` stores the IP address. So what are you asking?

Comment: If the ip address is treated as a string you can just strip the string so that you place each number in the array and then when you encounter the dot it knows the next number is a new element

Comment: The way you've done is the best and the easiest way to do it. If you try some out worldly hack (after a gruelling 36-year long search :P ) chances are the person who's going to maintain you code will have to too. (And what if he knows your address and happens to be a killer? :D )

Answer (score 3):

This is the answer to the question: Convert an IP-Address, given as a `std::string` to a `std::array`

I want to add this answer, because I think that "Ihor Drachuk"s answer can be modified to use more modern C++ elements.

All this many lines of code can be replaced by **one** statement, using `std::transform` and an ultra simple regex (\d+).

Please see the example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

// For easier reading and writing
using IPv4 = std::array<unsigned char, 4>;

// a regex for one or more digits
std::regex re{R"((\d+))"};

// Some test string. Can be anything
const std::string testIpString{"127.128.129.1"};

int main()
{
    // Here we will store the IP address as an array of bytes
    IPv4 ipV4{};
    
    // Convert IP-String to the array, using one statement. One liner
    std::transform(std::sregex_token_iterator(testIpString.begin(), testIpString.end(), re), {}, ipV4.begin(),
        [](const std::string& s){ return static_cast<unsigned char>(std::stoi(s));});
        
    // Some Debug output. Show result on screen    
    std::copy(ipV4.begin(), ipV4.end(), std::ostream_iterator<unsigned int>(std::cout,"\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! How do I assign the result to this array?    peer.ipv4[0] = XX;
   peer.ipv4[1] = XX;
   peer.ipv4[2] = XX;
   peer.ipv4[3] = XX;

Comment: If ````peer.ipv4[]```` is a ````std::array````, then simply replace ````ipV4.begin()```` with ````peer.ipv4.begin()````. If it is a C-Style array, then use ````&peer.ipv4[0]````

Answer (score 1):

> I have
>
> ```
> std::array<unsigned char, 4> ipv4 = {};
> ```

supposing *ipv4* contains in fact your address (else why to speak about it ?) and `ipv4[0]` is 90 etc just do

```
peer.ipv4[0] = ipv4[0];
peer.ipv4[1] = ipv4[1];
peer.ipv4[2] = ipv4[2];
peer.ipv4[3] = ipv4[3];
```

or use a loop

Comment: He probably wouldn't even need to use a loop as the compiler will unroll it anyway. :D

Comment: @d4rk4ng31 may be yes, considering the level of optimization the compilers are able to do, in a lot of cases to write in a way or an other does not change something on the result. Sometimes I think this is 'sad' to have the same result from a 'nice' code and an 'ugly' one... just a through of an old programmer starting with compilers without having all these optimizations ^^

Comment: True. Our professor does tell us his good old UNIX days when he used ed (yeah ed (is this the same as QED?)) and how the codes needed to be first written on paper before typing in a computer and how they had a better insight and conceptual clarity. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to parse string to ipv4 with validation of that string, you can try this function

*I assume this code should be faster than if use regex or some C++ features, but if you don't need speed-optimization, probably better to choose answer with less code and more clear*

```
using IPv4 = std::array<unsigned char, 4>;

// Speed-optimized variant
std::optional<IPv4> convertIPv4(const char* str)
{
    IPv4 result;
    size_t resultIndex = 0;

    const char* str2 = str;
    const char* ssEnd = nullptr;
    const char* ssStart = nullptr;

    int cnt = 0;

    while (true) {
        if (*str2 == '.' || *str2 == 0) {
            cnt++;

            if (!ssStart)
                return {};

            if (cnt == 5)
                return {};

            intptr_t diff = reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(ssEnd) - reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(ssStart);
            if ((diff < 0) || (diff > 2)) return {};

            if (diff == 2) {
                char c1 = *ssStart;
                char c2 = *(ssStart+1);
                char c3 = *(ssStart+2);

                if ((c1 < '0') || (c1 > '2')) return {};
                if ((c2 < '0') || (c3 < '0')) return {};
                if ((c2 > '9') || (c3 > '9')) return {};

                if (c1 == '2' && c2 >= '5' && c3 > '5') return {};

                result[resultIndex++] = (c1 - 48) * 100 + (c2 - 48) * 10 + (c3 - 48);
            } else if (diff == 1) {
                char c1 = *ssStart;
                char c2 = *(ssStart+1);

                if ((c1 < '0') || (c2 < '0')) return {};
                if ((c1 > '9') || (c2 > '9')) return {};

                result[resultIndex++] = (c1 - 48) * 10 + (c2 - 48);
            } else {
                char c1 = *ssStart;

                if ((c1 < '0') || (c1 > '9')) return {};

                result[resultIndex++] = c1 - 48;
            }

            // Return if all's done
            if (cnt == 4 && *str2 == 0) {
                return result;
            }

            ssEnd = nullptr;
            ssStart = nullptr;
        } else {
            if (!ssStart) ssStart = str2;
            ssEnd = str2;
        }

        str2++;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
IPv4 value = convertIPv4("127.0.0.1");
```

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but I think this will be harder and more unnecessary (unless it has any explicit upsides to it, which I am not able to figure out) than what the OP has already done :) And I prefer not to use `char*` in C++